# How to setup Development Environment for iPhone Applicaiton Development on a Windows 7 Machine?

Tags: iphone, mobile-application

I am an Android Developer. I want to get into iPhone development as well.
As mentioned in many sites, to develop an iPhone/iPad application we need a mac with Xcode as an IDE.
Is there a way to develop, build and test an iPhone application on Windows machine.
I came to know that DragonFire SDK is one of the option to do that.
But please guide me through the installation steps and steps to be followed to set up Dragon Fire SDK.
and if possible provide some links where I can find some info on how to start writing iPhone application on Windows.

Comment: What is the problem of buying a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

You can't developer iPhone app on windows in the for the native SDk (read Objective-C) you can use HTML apps and developer them on windows. Or use MonoTOuch (which will need to build the app on a mac).

And what is the problem with the Dragon Fire SDk, all the information you need is on there site.